# How can I get Compass to automatically import all stylesheets in app/assets/stylesheets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, compass-sass

I'm trying to add [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) to my Rails 3.2 app, using [compass-rails](https://github.com/compass/compass-rails). How can I get it to automatically import all of the stylesheets in `app/assets/stylesheets`? At the moment I have to manually do `@import 'filename';` in `application.css.scss` for each one.

Comment: I'm not aware of such a possibility. Does the number of files change a lot? Otherwise just make an additional partial which imports all other partials and then just import that one partial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put all your scss files (**except** *application.css.scss*) in a different folder:

> /application.css.scss
>
> /all/hello.css.scss
>
> /all/hi.css.scss

application.css.scss file like below will work.

```
@import "compass";
@import "all/*";
```

Answer (score 1):

#### For bundling stylesheets, use the asset pipeline

If you're using the asset pipeline, this should happen automagically with:

```
/*
 * In application.css
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

Docs: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives

The important caveat is *"Using Sprockets directives all Sass files exist within their own scope, making variables or mixins only available within the document they were defined in."*

#### For mixins & vars, have your imports in one place, then import once

If you're heavy on the functions, try having a file like `app/assets/stylesheets/base.css.scss` that contains `@import` directives (wildcard or not) for all your mixin and var files. Then you only need to `@import "base"` once for every stylesheet and can still bundle your css using sprockets directives.